# how to delete 10 row from a spedific index from a table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm new in PostgreSQL. Assume that I have a table (tbl_box) with thousands of records and it is growing, I want to delete 10 rows from a specific index (for example I want to delete 10 records from 50th row to 59th row) I wrote a function

You can see below:

```
- Function: public.signalreject()

-- DROP FUNCTION public.signalreject();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.signalreject()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
 rec   RECORD;
 cur CURSOR 
 FOR SELECT barcode,id
 FROM tbl_box where gf is null order by id desc;
 counter int ;
BEGIN
   -- Open the cursor
   OPEN cur;
   counter:=0;
   LOOP
    -- fetch row into the rec
      FETCH cur INTO rec;
    -- exit when no more row to fetch
      EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
      counter :=counter+1;

    -- build the output
      IF counter >= 50 and counter < 60  THEN 
         delete from tbl_box where barcode = rec.barcode;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   -- Close the cursor
   CLOSE cur;

END; $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.signalreject()
  OWNER TO Morteza;
```

I found that the cursor consumes memory and has a high CPU usage. What else except cursor you guys suggest me?
Is this a good way to do this?

I need the fastest way because it is important for me to delete in a shortest time.

Comment: This is a strange requirement, if I may say so. Why do you need to do that?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe the sensor is far from the barcode reader.Barcode Reader reads the barcode and inserts into tbl_box. after that, if the sensor recognized the product isn't normal, reject it then I have to remove that barcode from the tbl_box(the deleting scenario is my question)

Comment: That makes sense, but how do you arrive at a strange requirement like "delete the 50th to 59th row from a cursor"?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I got it from the analysis, and it's a little bit complex to explain.

Comment: Ok, get it. There is just the nagging suspicion in me that there might be a more elegant way to achieve your goal.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i don't know how much is strange to use cursor or not, I'm completely  new in PostgresSql and QT.about the reason why and how i arrived strange way, i can say, as i said above i need to delete 5 decade later.the only thing i find was i can gain my goal with cursor.if i find shorter and fastest way surly i use it

Comment: Sure. I'd use `DELETE FROM tab WHERE <condition>`.

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty elaborate, why not just do

```
delete from tbl_box 
where barcode in 
   ( select barcode 
     from tbl_box 
     where gf is null 
     order by id desc limit 10 offset 49
   );
```

assuming that `barcode` is unique. We skip 49 rows to start deleting 10 rows from row 50.